# Pull repository every five minutes

Tags: git

I want to pull data from a gitlab repository every two minuts.
I've added this script in my cronjob:

```
sudo cd /home/dev/web/question.***/public_html ; sudo git  pull ; sudo  git  add . ; sudo git   commit -m "update" ; sudo git push
```

But I get this email:

[image: Knipsel.png]

I've added the key to the server, what did I do wrong

Comment: Does your key have a passphrase? If so, you'll need to do something so that it can access your ssh-agent (or equivalent) - cron typically doesn't source your startup files and commands won't have many necessary environment variables available. Plenty of Q/A around stackoverflow and elsewhere on this problem and workarounds.

Comment: Why `sudo`? There is nothing that requires `sudo` when using Git.

Comment: The purpose of `sudo` is to allow a regular user do administrative tasks on the system (change system settings, start/stop/restart services etc). **Don't** use `sudo` for development.

Answer (score 1):

Problems in your cronjob:

1. `sudo` tries to ask for password but fails. Giving it a tty will not help because there is no user to enter password.
2. `sudo cd` doesn't work (it works in the shell under sudo but after that sudo invocation ended the shell is already exited and the effect of `cd` is lost).

My recommendation: run the commands without sudo at all. Run them from the crontab of the targeted user (root).

Or put the commands into a shell script and configure sudo to run the script without asking for password.